# простые числа которые возвращает функция

Tags: javascript

собственно задачка

Создай объект, с полями value и next, где next - функция, которая возвращает следующее от value простое число.

Когда делал первый раз, я просто вывел простые числа, мне скзаали неправильно.
Добавлю условие
например obj.value = 0. 
Я делаю obj.next() и value становится 1. 
Еще раз - 2. 
Еще раз - 3. 
Еще раз - 5 
Еще раз - 7 
Еще раз - 11

Comment: Секретный код где?

Comment: Ну так создайте объект с полями value и next, где next - функция, которая возвращает следующее от value простое число, а не просто выводите простые числа

Comment: Как я понимаю текст задания, value вводится пользователем, а next считается программой.

Comment: @Akina нет, есть объект по дефолту и функция.

Comment: @АндрейNOP ну дай подсказку, как начать, если бы было так все просто для меня я бы не спрашивал :(

Comment: Какая разница? Речь идёт о том, что нужен объект, у которого задаётся произвольное value, и функция возвращает соответствующее этому заданному извне значению value рассчитанное значение next. *как начать* Вот, скажем, неплохое описание: [MDN - Работа с объектами](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Comment: С точки зрения математики 1 не простое число

Comment: И всё таки код в студию

Comment: Да, добавляйте ваш код, а дальше мы покажем, как его доработать\изменить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаешь цикл который каждый раз увеличивает число на единицу, потом в этот цикл создаешь цикл который проверяет остаток от деления этого числа на числа от 2 до 9, если ни одно из делений не прошло на цело то выводишь это число, если прошло деление на цело то увеличиваешь число на единицу. Вот и вся арифметика.

Comment: Простые числа это те, что не делятся на числа от 2 до 9?